# Sharing charm set Data

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, sharing

i have next code:

In theory, this should create a e-mail with attached file. but i get error:

Error:

An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in App.exe but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: Unable to create StorageItems from the passed in object.
Additional information: Type mismatch.
Unable to create StorageItems from the passed in object.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Code:

```
internal async void OnDataReq(DataProviderRequest request)
    {
        var defferal = request.GetDeferral();
        var file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("SCLogFile.txt");
        request.SetData(RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(file));
        defferal.Complete();
    }
    private async void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "THIS IS A TITLE";
        e.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "THIS IS A DESCRIPTION";
        e.Request.Data.Properties.FileTypes.Add(".txt");
        e.Request.Data.SetDataProvider(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems, OnDataReq);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to share the files.

```
private async void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "THIS IS A TITLE";
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "THIS IS A DESCRIPTION";
    e.Request.Data.Properties.FileTypes.Add(".txt");
    var file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("SCLogFile.txt");
    e.Request.Data.SetStorageItems(file);
}
```

[MSDN sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84/sourcecode?fileId=43981&pathId=1926429020)

Comment: Problem is that somewhy, on Windows 8 devices i can't achieve attached file AND filled e-mail content. But on 8.1 all works fine

Comment: It all depends upon Mail app. Win8's Mail app is dumb, it doesn't do all the things at once but luckily Win8.1's Mail app is intelligent. Check out: [How to set subject and message part in email with attachment while share charm usage ?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3478925a-0945-4037-9bbf-4fc7ef6595c5/how-to-set-subject-and-message-part-in-email-with-attachment-while-share-charm-usage-?forum=winappswithcsharp)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem is that the data request is expecting a `IEnumerable<StorageItems>` and you are sending a stream.

I changed your function. This worked for me

`internal async void OnDataReq(DataProviderRequest request)
        {
            var defferal = request.GetDeferral();
            var file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("SCLogFile.txt");
            request.SetData(new[] {file});
            defferal.Complete();
        }`